# Lsyncd exclude files or folders not working

Tags: web-server, rsync, synchronization, lsyncd

I am using lsyncd for live syncing between master and slave and I want to exclude files like .htaccess and git files to slave server. I have configured like this:

sync
{

default.rsync,

source="/home/test/",

target="202.63.240.146:/home/test",

excludeFrom="/home/test/public_html/.htaccess",

rsync={archive = true, perms = true, owner = true, _extra = {"-a"}, rsh ="/usr/bin/ssh -l root -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa",}

}

But seems it's not working. Can anyone please correct my configuration. My lsyncd version is 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your `excludeFrom=` needs to be a file containing a simple list of files/directories to exclude. You appear to want to exclude the .htaccess file(s), in which case you'd want `exclude = { '.htaccess' }`. Refer to the 'Exclusions' section in the [lsyncd manual](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/).

Incidentally, your `_extra={'-a'}` may not be want you want. `-a` is equivalent to `-rlptgoD` ([see rsync manpage](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)). The lsyncd defaults for those options are

- [-r] `recurse = true`
- [-l] `links = true`
- [-t] `times = true`
- [-p] `perms = false`
- [-g] `group = false`
- [-o] `owner = false`
- [`-D`/`--devices`] <= not supported by lsyncd

Since you already override `perms`/`group`/`owner`, your `-a` is effectively equivalent to `--device`. [=recreate character and block devices at destination]